# Magento: Creating Multiple store and products display issue

Tags: magento-1.9

I have magento store (version 1.9) and 10 categories under root categories. Now I created sub-store following these steps:
    1) Admin-> System-> manage store
    2) Create website, created store (selected 'root category'), created store view[code: new]
    3) System->Configuration->General->Web: Change value of 'Add store code to Urls' to yes
    4) I can access substore with url: http://example.com/new and its working fine.

Problem: No products and cms pages are displaying in my site. How can I achive it  and also did I created sub-store properly?

Sharing your knowledge is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple stores creation was correct.

Display products on all stores: 
 Go to your manage products page, click select all, change the action dropdown to say "Change Attributes" and click submit. Then, on the websites tab, make sure your new site is checked in the "Add Product to Websites" area, and click save

CMS Pages: I had to go to edit every CMS page to display to all stores.